# Property of function $\varphi(x)=|x|$ on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, absolute-value, periodic-functions

> Define $\varphi(x)=|x|$ on $[-1,1]$ and extend the definition of $\varphi(x)$ to all real $x$ by requiring that $\varphi(x+2)=\varphi(x).$ How do you prove that for any $s,t$ 
>   $$
>   |\varphi(s)-\varphi(t)|\leqslant |s-t|?
> $$

I was going to do the following: For any $s,t$ exists $n,m$ such that $s=2n+\theta_s, t=2m+\theta_t$, where $\theta_s, \theta_t\in [-1,+1).$ Then $$|\varphi(s)-\varphi(t)|=|\varphi(s-2n)-\varphi(t-2m)|=|\varphi(\theta_s)-\varphi(\theta_t)|=||\theta_s|-|\theta_t||=$$$$=||s-2n|-|t-2m||=...$$ and I am stuck.

Comment: Hint: Note that $0\le \phi \le 1$, so 
$$|\phi(s) - \phi(t)|\le |s-t|$$
is trivially satisfied if $|s-t|\ge 1$. So you need only to deal with the case  $|s-t| <1$.

Comment: @JohnMa, How to investigate the case $|s-t|<1$?

Comment: Then you can just assume $s, t\in [-1,1]$ or in $[0,2]$ In the first case case $\phi(x) = |x|$ and so $|\phi(s) - \phi(t)| = | |s| - |t| |\le |s-t|$ by the triangle inequality. Similar for the second case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $\phi(x) = \min_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} |x-2k|$.

We have $|x-2k| \le |y-2k| + |x-y|$. Hence
$\phi(x) \le |y-2k| + |x-y|$, and since this holds for all $k$ we have
$\phi(x) \le \phi(y) + |x-y|$. Repeating this with $x,y$ interchanged
gives the desired result.

Comment: Nice result! +1:) By the way how to prove that $\phi(x)=\min \limits_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}|x-2k|$?

Comment: Note that it is $2$-periodic and $\phi(x) = |x|$ for $|x| \le 1$.

Comment: Using that we get $\phi(x)=\phi(x-2k)=|x-2k|$. How to get $\min$?

Comment: I don't understand your last remark. The fact that $\phi$ is $2$-periodic follows because the sets $\{ x-2k\}_k$ and $\{ x+2-2k\}_k$ are the same. Now restrict $|x| \le 1$ and note that $|x-2k| \ge 1$ for $k \neq 0$, hence $\phi(x) = |x|$.

Comment: Really! Sorry! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: No need. You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

for any $s,t\in \mathbb R$,
$$\phi(s)=\phi(s+2)=|s+2|\leq |s-t|+|t+2|=|s-t|+\phi(t+2)=|s-t|+\phi(t)     $$
$$\phi(s)-\phi(t) \leq |s-t|$$

By reversing the role of $s$ and $t$, we will get, 
$$\phi(t)-\phi(s) \leq |s-t|$$

Which shows that,$$\phi(s)-\phi(t)| \leq |s-t|$$

Comment: $\phi(s+2) = |s+2|$ is only possible when $s+2\in [-1,1]$.